# Anyone have method easier than this?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have this code and in reader. 
How can I get reader.Read without if methods?

```
        System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();

        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        string query = " select * FROM Other ORDER BY Type";
        command.CommandText = query;
        OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        txt.Text = "txtpertanyaan"+cLeft;
        this.Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = cLeft *25;
        txt.Left = 100;

        if (cLeft == 1)
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {

                reader.Read();

                txt.Text = reader["Type"].ToString();
                reader.Read();

            }
        }
        else if (cLeft ==2)
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {

                reader.Read();
                reader.Read();
                txt.Text = reader["Type"].ToString();
                reader.Read();

            }
        }
        else if (cLeft == 3)
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {

                reader.Read();
                reader.Read();
                reader.Read();
                txt.Text = reader["Type"].ToString();
                reader.Read();

            }
        }

        cLeft = cLeft+1;
        return txt;

    }
```

Thanks for your advice. I use dynamic textbox that add automatically if I click the button.

i want if cleft=1 then reader.read()=1, but i duuno if cleft=10? that must be i must write if condition until 10 times? its too long ...

Comment: Would be better in [CodeReview.SE]? What do you mean by _reader.Read its too long_ by the way?

Comment: You need a for loop there.

Comment: Where is the value of **cLeft** coming from? and what the logic you want to implement?

Comment: cLeft is variable for AddnewTextbox()......... i want if i click reader.read() added automatically to , like cleft=1 then readerread()=1 .. sorry make u all confuse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to get rid of the `If` statements you could use a `For` instead.

```
System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txt = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
command.Connection = connection;
string query = " select * FROM Other ORDER BY Type";
command.CommandText = query;
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

txt.Text = "txtpertanyaan"+cLeft;
this.Controls.Add(txt);
txt.Top = cLeft *25;
txt.Left = 100;

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < cLeft ; i++)
    {
        reader.Read();
    }
    txt.Text = reader["Type"].ToString();
    Reader.Read();
}    

cLeft = cLeft+1;
return txt;
```